# How can I remove the word "category" from wordpress category links

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the word category from my wordpress website

it is now like this
**[www.mywebsite.com/category/mycategory](http://www.mywebsite.com/category/mycategory)**
I want to change like this
**[www.mywebsite.commycategory](http://www.mywebsite.commycategory)**

I tried adding this code

```
 function remove_category( $string, $type )  {    
       if ( $type != 'single' && $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) )          {              $url_without_category = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );              return trailingslashit( $url_without_category );          }      return $string;  }     add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'remove_category', 100, 2);
```

I tried changing permalink structure

```
Settings >> Permalinks.
 Custom Structure -->‘/%category%/%postname%/’.
 Category Base ----> “. “
```

But this one  gives 404 error

I tried with YOAST seo plugin that one gave 404 errors

I also tried some plugins which were causing 404 errors as well

is there any way I can remove that word

Comment: also tried adding this line to my htaccess file
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I think that you can change it directly in WP Woocommerce administration, by editing the category itself, there is a perma link to the category, can you edit it there?

Comment: Dear Dave, thank you for your reply, but there is no way to change the structure directly from the category page